# writing apps for phonegap in java (with GWT, Vaadin etc.)

Tags: java, gwt, cordova, vaadin

I was looking at http://phonegap.com/ and I find the technology quite impressive.
And I was wondering with technologies like GWT or Vaadin, which convert Java code to Javascript, can it be used with phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Vaadin to create nice mobile application.

With [Vaadin TouchKit](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/touchkit) you can create native and HTML5 Application for cross-platforms.

For converting to native application, vaadin supports Apache Cordova & PhoneGap.

Comment: this looks actually very nice, but it is not free.

Comment: how exactly is the conversion supported?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with conversion supported? The conversion from a HTML5 Application to a native OS application?

Comment: exactly. Im interested how cany ou achieve that your code is converted via cordova to native OS application.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is [Mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) project introduced by *Daniel Kurka*

> By using gwt-phonegap and mgwt you can write applications that can be deployed into the app store or the market place with GWT.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/GettingStarted) is some start for you.